# Pandas - Exclude Timezone when using .apply(pd.to_datetime)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe with date columns that are in this initial format:

```
2018-04-30T22:43:36-04:00
```

I am using `df[['col]].apply(pd.to_datetime)` to convert them, however the conversion automatically adds +4 hours because of the timezone part. Is there any way to ignore that and convert the column to datetime without changing the timezone?

Thanks

Comment: There might be a better way, but what about `pd.to_datetime(col.str[:-6])`

Comment: We can manipulate the string to ignore the timezone. Other then that, it seems like an open issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13712